# ASP.NET WebApi Post Method - 404 When Passing Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest

I cannot for the life of me figure this out.  I have a web api controller with Get and Post methods.  The Get method works fine with and without parameters, but the post breaks when I try to add a String parameter to it.  Below is my code.

Route:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Controller:

```
public class AuditController : ApiController
{
    public String Post(String test)
    {
        return "Success : " + test;
    }

    public String Get(String test)
    {
        return "Success : " + test;
    }
}
```

Request:

```
    var request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:42652/Audit");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            writer.Write("test=TEST");
        }
        WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
```

I've tried many variations on the request, I feel like there's something simple I'm missing.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your route says it has a parameter named `id`, but in your method you pass a parameter named `test`. What shall it be? Also primitive type parameters are always tried to read from the Uri, so your post method won't work. I really suggest you to work through all the very nice ASP.Net Web API tutorials on the asp.net homepage!

Comment: Yes it is. Your Get-method represents the Route without the {id} parameter - because your id parameter is not present in the method. Your test-parameter is one of the optional query parameters, when you call `Audit?test=value`, but not on `Audit/value`. The answer you accepted sum this up good, but I still encourage you to really work through the tutorials!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since you are expecting parameter `test` to come from body of a request, you would need to decorate it with `FromBody` attribute. Example: `([FromBody]String test)`. This is not true for other complex types, for example: `Employee` class which is implicitly considered to be coming from Body.

Rearding GET request. It should be working only with test coming from query string `/Audit?test=Mike`

Following blog post has more details about parameter binding:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx

Also, I see that you are using WebRequest. Have you considered using HttpClient from System.Net.Http instead?

Comment: I added the FromBody attribute, and it will reach the service now, but  the 'test' variable inside the post method is null unfortunately.  I will have a look at HttpClient as well.

Comment: try sending just `=TEST` in your body.

Comment: For fuffuf fuffsake. WHY???? Thank you for this, it brought an end to an otherwise annoying morning. Mostly filled with totally unintuitive programming decisions.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `AuditController` to include the `FromBody` attribute :

```
public class AuditController : ApiController
{
    public String Post([FromBody]String test)
    {
        return "Success : " + test;
    }

    public String Get(String test)
    {
        return "Success : " + test;
    }
}
```

cf. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.frombodyattribute(v=vs.108).aspx